# How to create an EMR cluster and submit a spark-submit step using Dagster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-emr, dagster

I want to create a Dagster app that creates an EMR cluster and adds a spark-submit step, but due to a lack of documentation or examples I can't figure out how to do that (copilot also struggles with it :-)).

The idea is to create a scheduler with Dagster that creates an EMR cluster and runs scala-spark app as one of its steps.

Here's the code I have (it's not working correctly, but you may get a sense about what I was trying to do):

```
from dagster_shell import create_shell_command_op
from dagster_aws.emr.emr import EmrJobRunner
from dagster import graph, op

@op
def create_emr_cluster(context):
emr_job_runner = EmrJobRunner('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY', aws_secret_access='SECRET_KEY')
    cluster_id = emr_job_runner.create_cluster()
    step_dict = emr_job_runner.construct_step_dict_for_command('Spark Step', 'spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --deploy-mode cluster  s3://my-bucket/spark-examples.jar stage')
    emr_job_runner.add_job_flow_steps(None, cluster_id, [step_dict])

@graph
def my_graph():
    # a = create_shell_command_op('echo "hello, world!"', name="a") # this will invoke spark-submit on an existing cluster
    # a()
    create_emr_cluster()

my_job = my_graph.to_job()
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had most of your components correctly setup. You were only missing EMR job flow settings which sets the application you want to use(on EMR), core/task node setup and so on..
More details here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html

Dagster api has a function `run_job_flow` which takes this input and creates a cluster.
Sharing a sample code snippet

```
from dagster_aws.emr import EmrJobRunner
REGION="us-east-1"
emr_cluster_config = {
    "Applications": [
        {
            "Name": "Spark"
        }
    ],
    "JobFlowRole": "SomeRole",
    "Instances": {
        "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet-1",
        "EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup": "sg-slave",
        "EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup": "sg-master",
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": True,
        "TerminationProtected": False,
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "InstanceCount": 1,
                "EbsConfiguration": {
                    "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                        {
                            "VolumeSpecification": {
                                "SizeInGB": 32,
                                "VolumeType": "gp3"
                            },
                            "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceType": "r6g.2xlarge",
                "Name": "EMR Master"
            },
            {
                "InstanceCount": 2,
                "EbsConfiguration": {
                    "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                        {
                            "VolumeSpecification": {
                                "SizeInGB": 256,
                                "VolumeType": "gp3"
                            },
                            "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                "InstanceType": "r6g.2xlarge",
                "Name": "EMR Core"
            },
            {
                "InstanceCount":2,
                "EbsConfiguration": {
                    "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                        {
                            "VolumeSpecification": {
                                "SizeInGB": 256,
                                "VolumeType": "gp3"
                            },
                            "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "InstanceRole": "TASK",
                "InstanceType": "r6g.2xlarge",
                "Name": "EMR Task"
            }
        ]
    },
    "StepConcurrencyLevel": 1,
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.36.0",
    "LogUri": "s3n://<somebucket>/logs/",
    "EbsRootVolumeSize": 32,
    "ServiceRole": "emr-role",
    "Name": "<cluster_name>"
}
emr = EmrJobRunner(region=REGION)
# This step create the cluster
cluster_id = emr.run_job_flow(emr_cluster_config)
step_name = 'test_step'
step_cmd = ['ls', '/']
step_ids = emr.add_job_flow_steps(
     cluster_id, [emr.construct_step_dict_for_command(step_name, step_cmd)]
)
```

You can also look at the test cases on dagster [repo](https://github.com/uranusbeam/bit-dagster/blob/d26ff47f4ba8441128c6ce47b9c328f6496a91d9/python_modules/libraries/dagster-aws/dagster_aws_tests/emr_tests/test_emr.py), it does provide a very good examples for the same.